# play a youtube video by clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

want to `play` - `stop` - `pause` - a youtube video by clicking on corresponding buttons
according to several tutorials - this code should work - but it doesn't
clicking on `btnplay` for the first time - youtube logo is removed and it seems it will play - but that's all
clicking each next time - nothing happens

```
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<button id='btnplay'>PLAY</button>
<iframe id="player" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rDT93EN_nVI?rel=0&enablejsapi=1"></iframe>

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){
    player = new YT.Player('player');
}

$(btnplay).on('click', function(){
    console.log('clicked'); // works
    player.playVideo();  // doesn't work
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```html
<iframe id="video" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/rDT93EN_nVI?enablejsapi=1&html5=1&mute=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<button id="btnplay">PLAY</button>
```

```js
// global variable for the player
var player;

// this function gets called when API is ready to use
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
  // create the global player from the specific iframe (#video)
  player = new YT.Player("video", {
    events: {
      // call this function when player is ready to use
      onReady: onPlayerReady
    }
  });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
  // bind events
  var playButton = document.getElementById("btnplay");
  playButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    player.playVideo();
  });
}

// Inject YouTube API script
var tag = document.createElement("script");
tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```

Reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Comment: it works only if `&mute=1` is inside the iframe.src - but I need the sound, of course

Comment: I keep forgetting autoplay won't work unless the video is muted. It makes sense but it's also easy to get stuck because of this issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `player` is undefined when you call the button click. This is because the IFrame Player API is not load asynchronously (as per the [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference))

Try the following javascript:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

let player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){
    player = new YT.Player('player');
}

$(btnplay).on('click', function(){
    console.log('clicked'); // works
    player.playVideo();  // doesn't work
});
```

Comment: Really? This codepen: https://codepen.io/GeneralPoxter/pen/gORLzYM?editors=1011 works fine for me.

Comment: your codepen doesn't work for me. clicking on the button - the video doesn't start to play

Comment: I see now - it works only if  `&mute=1` is added to `iframe` - but I need the sound, of course

Comment: Hm it also seems to pause shortly after I press play.

Comment: it doesn't pause for me - it plays fluently to the end

Comment: I meant without the added `&mute-1`

Comment: without `mute=1` - it doesn't start to play at all for me